# How to refresh Html.DropDownGroupList after another dropdown changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have difficulties to refresh an Html.DropDownGroupList.
I have two dropdowns which depends on each other: Makes and Models. The Models dropdown should be grouped, as you can see in the attached screenshot.

[image]

When I enter in the page the Models dropdown is filled with data and it is grouped correctly, but when I change the first dropdown, the Model is not refreshing correctly.

In the controller I have this code:

```
public ActionResult GetModels(string id)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            int number;
            bool result = Int32.TryParse(id, out number);
            if (!result)
                return Json(null);

            var selectedMake = makeRepository.GetMakeByID(number);
            var list1 = db.Models.Where(m => m.MakeID == selectedMake.ID).ToList();

            List<GroupedSelectListItem> models = new List<GroupedSelectListItem>();
            foreach (var items in list1)
            {
                models.Add(new GroupedSelectListItem
                {
                    Text = items.Name,
                    Value = items.ID.ToString(),
                    GroupName = items.GroupName,
                    GroupKey = items.GroupName
                });
            }
            ViewBag.Alma = models;
            return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                
        }
        return Json(null);
    }
```

and in the View :

```
@Html.DropDownGroupList("models", ViewBag.Alma as List<GroupedSelectListItem>, "Select Model", new
{
    @class = "dropdown-toggle col-md-9 form-control"
})
```

This is the code where I try to refresh the dropdown:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetModels")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { id: $("#makes").val() },
    success: function (models) {
        if (window.console) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(models))
        }
        $.each(models, function (i, model) {                        
            $("#models").append
                ('<optgroup label="'+ model.GroupName + '"><option value="' + model.Value + '">' +
                 model.Text + '</option></optgroup>'
                 );
        });
    }
});
```

This is the way the dropdown looks after the refresh

[image]

The grouping is not working anymore. I know that this is the problem:

```
$("#models").append('<optgroup label="'+ model.GroupName + '"><option value="' + model.Value + '">' + model.Text + '</option></optgroup>');
```

but how to do this ajax call to group my dropdown? I don't have so much experience with ajax, javascript.

Can you please advise how to refresh the Model dropdown?

Comment: What plugin are you using (`DropDownGroupList()` is not part of MVC)? And what is you script for updating the 2nd dropdownlist

Comment: You need to show the controller method for your `GetModels()` method - its not returning the data in the correct structure, which needs to be a nested collection - i.e. a collection of a view model that contains properties for the group name and a a collection of a view model containing properties for the option value and text

Comment: I've updated the question, I added the GetModels() method. I followed this exemple for DrodownGroupList : http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2014/01/html5-dropdownlist-optgroup-tag-in-mvc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetModels()` method is returning `List<GroupedSelectListItem>` which is a special class used by the `DropDownGroupList()` method and is not suitable for building your html (at least without a lot of extra code to group data in the script).

Start by creating view models to represent the hierarchical data you need

```
public class GroupVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OptionVM> Options { get; set; }
 }
public class OptionVM
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then modify the controller to group your data and project the results to the view model

```
public ActionResult GetModels(int? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue)
    {
        return Json(null);
    }
    var data = db.Models.Where(x => x.MakeID == id.Value).GroupBy(x => x.GroupName).Select(x => new GroupVM()
    {
        Name = x.Key,
        Options = x.Select(y => new OptionVM()
        {
            Value = y.ID,
            Text= y.Name
        })
    });
    return Json(data);
}
```

And modify your script to

```
var models = $('#models'); // cache it
$('#makes').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetModels")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            models.empty(); // clear existing options
            $.each(data, function (index, group) {
                var optGroup = $('<optgroup></optgroup>').attr('label', group.Name);
                $.each(group.Options, function (index, option) {
                    var option = $('<option></option>').val(option.Value).text(option.Text);
                    optGroup.append(option);
                });
                models.append(optGroup);
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Works fine! :) Thank you very much!